# Are there Pythagorean triples of polygonal areas?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

To Coda:

According to the Pythagorean theorem, the sum of the areas of squares on the legs of a right triangle equals the area of the one on its hypotenuse. But the same is true if one [builds pentagons](https://www.geogebra.org/m/vtDjfM6g) or $n$-gons on the sides instead of squares.

There are cases when all three square areas are integers (for Pythagorean triples, for example). Are there such cases for other polygons?

Coda:

---

NOTE: my original question was the one below

Given the polygonal number formula:
$(n^2*(s-2) - n*(s-4))/2$, 
one can list, for example, the square numbers (s=4):
$f(n) = [1 , 4 , 9 , 16 , 25 , 36 , 49 , 64 , 81, ...]$
or the pentagonal numbers (s=5):
$f(n) = [1 , 5 , 12 , 22 , 35 , 51 , 70 , 92, ...]$. By inspection we see for the pentagonal numbers that f(4) + f(7) = f(8). Is this analogous to the Pythagorean theorem? Where f(3)+f(4)=f(5).

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are asking. Do you mean that you want an integer sided Pentagon such that the sum of the squares of the four smallest sides equals the square of the largest side?

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/m/vtDjfM6g I want this with integers

Comment: Please add that to your question so that it is clear to others what you want to ask. Since "square" means both: ''a number times the same number" and "a rectangle with each side equal", it leads to confusion. P.S. sorry for the informal definitions.

Comment: To answer your question below the line. No, it is not analogous or related to the Pythagorean theorem, but infinitely many such triples can be generated, see [Hansen, Arithmetic of pentagonal numbers](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/8-1/hansen.pdf).

Comment: They must be related. Maybe you can tell me if you think the polygonal numbers for s = 4 is related to the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Why must they? It is related to square numbers for the trivial reason that those are squares of integers. So when the sum of perfect squares is a perfect square the integers must form a Pythagorean triple. The areas of other polygons built on the sides of a right triangle are proportional to the same squared Pythagorean triples, as you can see from the answer below. But what do they have to do with other polygonal numbers? There might be some geometric interpretation to the sum of two of them being another one of them, but the Pythagorean theorem is not it.

Answer (score 5):

The area scale factor between the square and the other polygon is the same for all sides. Thus, whatever polygons you put on the sides instead of squares with integer areas, you can scale the entire triangle by the square root of that factor to make all the polygon areas come out to the same integers as the squares did.

Comment: What do you mean by the scale factor between the square and the other polygon? Like if I have a square with sides 1 and I scale this to 2 then this is the same a scaling the sides of a pentagon by 2?

Comment: Polygonal numbers (except for squares) **do not** exactly represent the areas of the corresponding polygons, that's the trick.

Comment: @PhilipYeranosian: I edited the answer to make it "area scale factor" to perhaps make it a bit clearer. E.g. an equilateral triangle with side length $a$ has area $\frac{\sqrt3}4a^2$, i.e. $\frac{\sqrt3}4$ times the area of a square with that side length. So if you have a triangle where the squares of the side lengths are integers, you can scale it by $a\to\sqrt{\frac4{\sqrt3}}a$, and the areas of the equilateral triangles constructed on each side will be integers.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: I'm not sure whether that comment was directed at me or at the OP? (If at me, I'm afraid I don't know what you mean – I didn't say anything about polygonal numbers.)

Comment: @joriki Indeed you didn't. Then I guess my comment was misdirected.

Comment: Is it obvious that polygonal areas come out as integers only when they are proportional to the squares of a Pythagorean triple?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin You’re right. And so I realized that for s>4, you have to add the polygonal number for n-1 and s-2. And so the true pentagonal polygonal numbers for example are 1,6,15,28. Note that this sequence is assigned to the hexagonal numbers.